# selecting large amount of data using batch and insert the data into other table using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, batch-processing

I have a table with few  million rows. I need to transfer that data using batches to another table using SSIS. I tried with below query to get records as batches  but the loop doesn't stop.

```
while exists (select top 1 * from dbo.test
               where (date > '2018-04-25'
                       and date < '2018-04-27'))
Begin

select * from dbo.test
where id in ( select top (1000) id
               where (date > '2018-04-25'
                      and date < '2018-04-27'))
                      order by date asc 
End
```

Comment: Look closely at your logic. If there is even a single row that meets the criteria this will never stop because the row ALWAYS exists.

Comment: You have to update your test table data inside the loop, otherwise, it will never stop looping

Comment: I'm fairly certain you don't need the loop at all, nor the top 1000. Just run your select and you will be fine. I'm guessing you put the top 1000 in just to test the loop, but now you're going down a very excruciatingly path to very slow queries.

Comment: This is expected behavior.   You haven't written any code to stop the loop, therefore the loop doesn't stop.

Comment: Do you think the results of the first query will change based on the loop?

Answer (score 2):

This should be the only query you need:

```
select * from dbo.test
where id in ( select id
              where (date > '2018-04-25'
                 and date < '2018-04-27'))
```

In SSIS, on the Destination Editor in your Data Flow tab for this operation, enter `1000` for the "Rows per batch:" setting. No need to try to do this with a loop and top 1000. I would highly recommend against that approach as the performance will be worse. Possibly exponentially so.